# creating a custom control in iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have made a custom control in my application. It is like a combo box. when a button is clicked a table view will appear. user selects a row from that table and the value will be displayed on either textfield or on the button's lable. Now i wanted to know, if it is okay if i make a custom control like this in iphone. Or will it be rejected when i submit it to app store??? i feel like i am taking a risk here???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly ok, and in most cases, encouraged.

The only argument against it would be that it might have been easier and less work to just use a normal button and a `UIPickerView`, but that is entirely subjective and completely up to you.

Comment: i forgot to mention that my table view will appear right below the button. the width of the table is same as the width of a button. so that it looks exactly like a drop down button. i am not displaying the table in modal view or alert view or nything like that. my only concern is will this kind of controll be approved by app store???

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a problem with it. Apple will only take issue if the control uses private APIs or something...